# Select particular instance of a model with Foreign Key to another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have these models

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    # SET_NULL ensures that when a company is deleted, their reviews remains
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # SET_NULL ensures that when a user is deleted, their reviews get deleted too
    review_text = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Your Review: (Maximum of 200 Words)')
    rating = Int_max.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    date_added = models.DateField('Review Date', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_text

class Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Your Response')
    date_added = models.DateField('Response Date', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.response

class ResponseReply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Your Reply")
    date_added = models.DateField('Response Date', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reply
```

How to I select ResponseReply belonging to a particular response which also has a foreign key to a particular review.

My view rather returns a list instead of an object of the Review Model since there are more than one review. Below is my view:

```py
def profile_company(request):
    print(request.user)
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, user=request.user)
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, company=company)
    responses = get_list_or_404(Response, review=review)
    response = get_object_or_404(Response, review=review)
    responses = get_list_or_404(Response, review=review)
    reply = get_object_or_404(Response, response=response)
    company_reviews = company.review_set.all()
    total_reviews = len(company_reviews)
    print(company.average_rating)
    form = ResponseForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid:
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.review = review
            data.save()
            return redirect('profile_company')
    context = {
        'company': company,
        'company_reviews': company_reviews,
        'total_reviews': total_reviews,
        'form': form,
        'responses': responses,
        'reply': reply,
        

    }
    return render(request, 'companyusers/profile_company.html', context)
```

The problem is when I call `response = get_object_or_404(Response, review=review)` it fails since the review can be more than one. How do I select a particular response belonging to a particular review. To enable me select associated replies.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `response = get_object_or_404(Response, review=review, reply=my_reply)`, with `my_reply` the reply, but this is not per se guaranteed to be a single object. But I'm not following what the reply is in this case, the modeling looks quite "chaotic".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, it is guaranteed to be one Response. One Reply has one Response and one Response has One review. The problem with filter children by parent, is that you get multiple children, but if you select by child you get only one parent. However, he should loose the Review foreign key and not allow ResponseReply to be attached to a review directly and with current code, you can't do that anyway, cause Response cannot be null on the ResponseReply model, so the Review link is redundant.

Comment: I have removed the foreign key on of Review on ResponseReply, It is obviously redundant.

response = get_object_or_404(Response, review=review, reply=my_reply)
please how did you instantiate my_reply because that may seem to be the solution to my challenge.

Thank you so much for making out time to review my qs.